# Continuous function to a induced topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, and for $\alpha$, $A_\alpha\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open set and $f_\alpha:U_\alpha\subset X\longrightarrow\ A_\alpha$ a bijection such that $f_\alpha(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta)$ is open in $A_\alpha$ for every $\alpha,\beta$. If we give $X$ the topology $\tau=\{D\subset X: \forall\,\alpha, f_\alpha(D\cap U_\alpha) \text{ is open on }A_\alpha\}$, is $f_\alpha$ continuous?

EDIT: So far, if I fix $\alpha$, then I have to check that given $B\subset A_\alpha$ open, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is open on $X$. I have checked that $f_\alpha(f^{−1}_\alpha(B)\cap U_\alpha)$ is open on $A_\alpha$. However for $\beta\neq\alpha$ I am not able to prove anything.

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @LeeMosher So far, if I fix $\alpha$, then I have to check that given $B\subset A_\alpha$ open, then $f_{\alpha}^{-1}(B)$ is open on $X$. I have checked that $f_\alpha(f_\alpha^{-1}(B)\cap U_\alpha)$ is open on $A_\alpha$. However for $\beta\neq\alpha$ I am not able to prove anything.

Comment: In which universe do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ live?

Comment: @MichaëlCadilhac I suppose that they belong to an arbitrary index set. However, it could be, for example, the set of natural numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is negative even in the following simple case. Let $X=U_1=U_2=A_1=A_2=\Bbb R$, $f_1$ be the identity map and $f_2$ be any non-open bijection of the reals. Assume that both functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous on the space $(X,\tau)$. Since for any open subset $D$ of the reals the set $D=f_1^{-1}(D)\in\tau$, $f_2(D)$ is an open subset of the reals. That is the map $f_2$ is an open bijection of the reals, a contradiction.